# What driver has replaced ldusb ? (Write a Real Linux Driver tutorial)

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am watching Greg KH tutorial from 2008 about writing a Linux Driver :
http://video.linux.com/videos/write-a-real-linux-driver-greg-kh-2008

The first thing he does in the tutorial is unloading the ldusb module.

```
rmmod ldusb
```

I am currently running a ubuntu 14.04 based distribution and I don't have a ldusb module ([see here](http://0bin.net/paste/zt-Yjpx6BtgYLUDI#dXfva28yCNNYq8updct+Vvyb02Ka7oOtDnFtZFWi87Q) the output of lsmod).

What module should I unload to follow this tutorial ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ...  I don't have a ldusb module ...

Of course you don't. Because you don't have the hardware that he told the audience to plug into their machine about 2 minutes in. Either get the same hardware that they're using or ignore the hardware-specific bits and move on.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are not seeing the module is because it is not already loaded, you can load the module using modprobe ldusb and check if it is loaded by lsmod|grep ldusb.

It is not mandatory to have the hardware installed to load the module.Kernel Modules can be loaded even if someone doesn't have hardware(But driver won't be of much use without hardware)